Comparison of Counted Deviations in Sample Means from Sub-Gaussian Variables
Consider two $1-$sub-gaussian variables $X, Y$, and we i.i.d. sample $X$ $n$ times $(X_1,...,X_n)$; and sample $Y$ $m$ times, $(Y_1,...,Y_m)$, where $n\geq m$ and $\mu_x<S<\mu_y$, $S$ is a constant level. We have such a quantity: $N_X = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I} (\hat{\mu}_X(i) < S)$, where $\hat{\mu}_X(i) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^iX_j}{i}$. The quantity $N_X$ describes how many times the sampled average of $X$ is below $S$. Similarly, we have $N_Y = \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{I} (\hat{\mu}_Y(i) < S)$.
In intuition, $N_X \geq N_Y$truly hold since $\mu_Y>S>\mu_X$ makes it high probability happen $\hat{\mu}_X<S$ and low probability happen $\hat{\mu}_Y<S$.
Here, we want to bound the probability of such event $N_X\leq N_Y$ explicitly. i.e., $P(N_X\leq N_Y)$ using $\mu_X, \mu_Y, S, n, m$ these quantities?
I have tried to decompose it as $P(N_X\leq N_Y) \leq P(N_X \leq \mathbb{E}(N_X)-\delta) + P(N_Y \geq \mathbb{E}(N_Y)+\delta)$, where $\delta \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(N_X) - \mathbb{E}(N_Y)}{2}$ is some constant. For both terms, we need to find these expectations and use some concentration inequalities to bound the probability, but I did not figure it out. Maybe there are some other ways?
